# Run A Prediction On Pre-Created Model/Endpoint

Tags: python, jupyter, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker, inference

I have created an endpoint through a separate script in a Sagemaker Jupyter notebook instance. I am trying to get access to that endpoint in another script and run an inference on it.

I am unaware over anything I can run to specifically pull an endpoint and assign it to a variable.

In the past I deployed an endpoint linked to an RCF like so:

```py
#This creates an endpoint
rcf_inference = rcf.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
)
print('Endpoint name: {}'.format(rcf_inference.endpoint))
```

I used the rcf_inference variable in the other script to run an inference, and I would like to follow the same route here, but can't redeploy the rcf.

```py
#This grabs the data we want to test from an s3
s3=boto3.client('s3')
obj=s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=testingDataKey)


prediction_data = pandas.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
prediction_data_numpy=np.array(prediction_data)

#This line runs the test data and stores it in results. 
#I do not have a rcf_inference variable, so I can't run it this way though.
#results = rcf_inference.predict(prediction_data_numpy)

predictor = RealTimePredictor(endpoint=endpoint, accept=CONTENT_TYPE_CSV)
results=predictor.predict(prediction_data_numpy.tobytes())
```

There has to be some way to call my endpoint and assign it to this variable right? My goal is to take this variable and run an inference on it just like I did in the other script. I get "unable to evaluate payload provided" when I run it through my current method.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you're looking for a "DescribeEndpoint" API call.

Something along the following lines might be what you're looking for:

```
sagemaker.Session().sagemaker_client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
```

Take a look at the following code snippet from the sagemaker-python-sdk repository for a working example: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/db6c55ec4a21dbd59e264e2ab9fc1e8494aa781f/tests/integ/test_mxnet_train.py#L131

Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct using the RealTimePredictor. As long as you are in the same region and using the correct endpoint name then things should work as expected.

I'm assuming RCF stands for RandomCutForest, which is a supported algorithm in the SageMaker Python SDK. In which case, most likely the predictor class that is provided when deploying that algorithm might have different configurations in terms of default serialization/deserialization. Please use that class or copy the same configurations: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/amazon/randomcutforest.py#L152